# Passing Date to Url Tag Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a date to a URL Tag. Here is my url regex:

```
url(r'^fund_details/?startDate=(?P<date_index>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/?offset(?P<date_offset>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/
```

and my url tag:

```
{% url 'fund_monitor:fund_details' start_date offset %}
```

But i get this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '08-18-2017'
```

Note my start date is `'08-18-2017'`. I think it is because my regex is looking for a number rather than a string. However, I need the `-` in between the numbers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Query arguments are not part of the URL as captured by Django.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of achieving the intended result would be specifying the URL structure up until the query string, and implement the logic in a view function or class. Practically speaking, you should have the following:

`urls.py` (or whatever filename containing the URL bindings):

```
url(r'^fund_details/$', YourViewClass.as_view(), name="url_alias")
```

(Note the `$` symbol in the end - as far as my experience is concerned, that should work even if your full URL has a query string in the end.)

`views.py` or other arbitrarily-named file:

```
def handle_request(request):
    start_date = request.GET["start_date"]
    date_offset = request.GET["date_offset"]

    # Do your own validation with the acquired input
    # Compute the output with the just validated data
```

Constructing a query string as `?startDate=01-01-2017&offset=01-01-2016` is easily (or rather, automatically) done using a HTML form.